# How to highlight cells with decimals or characters less than 3 and more than 6 using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA coding and please help me create a VBA script with the following conditions.

1. Should highlight cells containing decimals.
2. Should highlight cells with number of characters less than 3 or more than 6.
3. Should execute from Column G (G1) till the last row last used cell.

My data is alphanumeric or numeric.

I have tried using `characters.count` and `Value.count` but it didn't work out. Hope it will work with `len`, but I'm not sure how to start with.

Attached is the sample excel file with highlighted cells

I have tried the below code.  Since my data is alphanumeric, characters count doesn't help.

```
Sub HighlightCells()
Range(" G1").Select
Do
  If ActiveCell.Characters.Count < 3 Then
    With Selection.Interior
      .Pattern = xlSolid
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .Color = 65535
      .TintAndShade = 0
      .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
  End If
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 'need to run in every row till the last row     last used cell
Loop Until ActiveCell = ""

Range(" G1").Select
Do
  If ActiveCell.Characters.Count > 6 Then
    With Selection.Interior
      .Pattern = xlSolid
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .Color = 65535
      .TintAndShade = 0
      .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
  End If
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 'need to run in every row till the last row   last used cell
Loop Until ActiveCell = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the conditions ***AND*** conditions or ***OR*** conditions ???

Comment: Do you want the cell highlighted if it contains ***no*** characters ???

Comment: Condition is OR only. Blank cells with no characters need not be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Before:

[image]

This code is almost a direct translation of your description in English into VBA:

```
Sub Dural()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, s As String, L As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        s = Cells(i, "G").Text
        L = Len(s)
        If InStr(1, s, ".") > 0 Or (L < 3 Or L > 6) Then
            With Cells(i, "G").Interior
              .Pattern = xlSolid
              .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
              .Color = 65535
              .TintAndShade = 0
              .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gary. it works brilliant..!! Can you include other rows in it too. I mean G,H,I,J...BX,BY,BZ.It works only in G row as of now.

Comment: @Mahesh  I would need a complete list of the

Comment: Hi Gary, I can't see your comment completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRow = Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + _
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Row
    LastCol = Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column + _
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1).Column
    For Each cll In Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    s = cll.Value
    l = Len(s)
    If ((l > 0) And (l < 3)) Or (l > 6) Or (s Like "*#.#*") _
        Then cll.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next cll
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub